# How to validate algebra expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to Regular expression validations in JavaScript.

My textbox allows the user to enter a formula which needs to be validated client side.

The formula can be made of following  operators:

```
+
_
*
/
(
)
%
```

These are the only symbols allowed in my textbox.

I need to validate the formula, which should have a form like `CurrentbaseSalary+CurrentMBP(BPI)`. Something like `+BPI-CBI(` should not be considered valid.

Comment: Do you also want to make sure that expressions like `BPI++CBI()` are invalid?

Comment: yes. They are invalid. should be a valid algeabric expresssion

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regexp :

```
/^(\([+*%\/\-\d\s]+\)|[+*%\/\-\d\s]+)+$/.test('YOUR STRING')
```

this regexp check if you are using your allowed symbols and if parenthesis matches, but it cant check if "CurrentbaseSalary" is positive or negative, "CurrentMBP(BPI)" neither.

Some code, or more detailed example could help to find a solution.